# Userspace pointer passed as an argument to a custom systemcall is getting changed inside the systemcall

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm currently working on a Linux kernel system call, and I've encountered an issue that I'd like to understand better. The problem arises when I pass a user-space pointer as an argument to the system call. Although I'm certain of the pointer's value when I pass it, the value appears to change when printed inside the system call. Here's the relevant code:

system call code:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(hello, char __user*, userland)
{
    char *c = "test string \n";

    printk("copying bytes to %p \n",(void*)userland);

    int n = copy_to_user((void *)userland,(void *)c,14);
    return 0;
}
```

userspace code:

```
void *addr = 0xffffff000000;
void *ptr = mmap(addr,256,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
printf("address allocated by mmap %p \n",ptr);
syscall(451,(char *)ptr);
printf("contents of the string : %s \n",(char *)ptr);
```

following is the output of the code.

```
address allocated by mmap 0xffffff000000
copying bytes to 0x00000e8084e0
contents of the string : test string
```

It's clear from the output that the address printed inside the system call differs from the value initially passed. However, when we print the contents of the address, we see that the string has been correctly copied. What could be causing this apparent address discrepancy?

I appreciate any insights or explanations regarding this behavior. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @MarcoBonelli, it works. It was excatly what i was looking for.